# How to make regular expression to scrape complex array from a following code using php

Tags: php, javascript, regex

i want to retrieve some data from this website: 
http://sites.target.com/site/en/spot/search_results.jsp?&mapType=enhanced&startAddress=72756&startingLat=36.322757720947266&startingLong=-93.99922943115234&_requestid=2573952

There are following lines in the html source of above web page,

```
<script>
    function GetMap(){
    var results = new Array();
    results[results.length] = {"lat" : "36.299484", "lon" : "-94.173495", "id" : "2498", "name" : "test", "phoneNumber" : "(479) 986-1100", "hours" : "test", "address" : {"city" : "Rogers", "state" : "AR", "zip" : "72758", "street" : "2404 Promenade Blvd" }, "concepts" : [{"name" : "Pharmacy", "phoneNumber" : "(479) 986-1101", "hours" : "<b>M-Fr:</b> 10:00AM-7:00PM<br><b>Sa:</b> 10:00AM-7:00PM" }, {"name" : "PhotoLab", "hours" : "<b>M-Fr:</b> 9:00AM-9:00PM<br><b>Sa:</b> 9:00AM-9:00PM<br><b>Su:</b> 10:00AM-8:00PM" }, {"name" : "Wine"}, {"name" : "Starbucks"}]};
    results[results.length] = {"lat" : "36.1157", "lon" : "-94.1555", "id" : "1470", "name" : "test", "phoneNumber" : "(479) 443-5517", "hours" : "test", "address" : {"city" : "Fayetteville", "state" : "AR", "zip" : "72703", "street" : "3545 N Shiloh Dr" }, "concepts" : [{"name" : "Pharmacy", "phoneNumber" : "(479) 443-5628", "hours" : "<b>M-Fr:</b> 9:00AM-7:00PM<br><b>Sa:</b> 9:00AM-5:00PM<br><b>Su:</b> 11:00AM-5:00PM" }]};
    results[results.length] = {"lat" : "36.6738", "lon" : "-93.2257", "id" : "2098", "name" : "test", "phoneNumber" : "(417) 243-4500", "hours" : "test", "address" : {"city" : "Branson", "state" : "MO", "zip" : "65616", "street" : "1200 Branson Hills Pkwy" }, "concepts" : [{"name" : "Pharmacy", "phoneNumber" : "(417) 243-4513", "hours" : "<b>M-Fr:</b> 9:00AM-9:00PM<br><b>Sa:</b> 9:00AM-6:00PM<br><b>Su:</b> 9:00AM-6:00PM" }, {"name" : "PhotoLab", "phoneNumber" : "(417) 243-4500", "hours" : "<b>M-Fr:</b> 12:00PM-6:00PM<br><b>Sa:</b> 12:00PM-6:00PM<br><b>Su:</b> 12:00PM-6:00PM" }, {"name" : "Wine"}, {"name" : "Starbucks"}]};
    results[results.length] = {"lat" : "37.0849", "lon" : "-94.474", "id" : "774", "name" : "test", "phoneNumber" : "(417) 659-8755", "hours" : "test", "address" : {"city" : "Joplin", "state" : "MO", "zip" : "64801", "street" : "3151 E 7th St" }, "concepts" : [{"name" : "FreshGrocery"}, {"name" : "Pharmacy", "phoneNumber" : "(417) 206-3377", "hours" : "<b>M-Fr:</b> 9:00AM-9:00PM<br><b>Sa:</b> 9:00AM-6:00PM<br><b>Su:</b> 9:00AM-6:00PM" }, {"name" : "Wine"}, {"name" : "Starbucks"}]};
    results[results.length] = {"lat" : "37.1511", "lon" : "-93.2623", "id" : "1031", "name" : "test", "phoneNumber" : "(417) 889-1511", "hours" : "test", "address" : {"city" : "Springfield", "state" : "MO", "zip" : "65804", "street" : "1825 E Primrose St" }, "concepts" : [{"name" : "FreshGrocery"}, {"name" : "Pharmacy", "phoneNumber" : "(417) 520-1745", "hours" : "<b>M-Fr:</b> 9:00AM-7:00PM<br><b>Sa:</b> 9:00AM-5:00PM<br><b>Su:</b> 11:00AM-5:00PM" }, {"name" : "PhotoLab", "phoneNumber" : "(417) 889-1511", "hours" : "<b>M-Fr:</b> 12:00PM-6:00PM<br><b>Sa:</b> 12:00PM-6:00PM<br><b>Su:</b> 12:00PM-6:00PM" }, {"name" : "Starbucks"}]};
```

I want to seperate latitude, longitude,id, name, phone number, city, state, zip code.

is it possible to parse data from above javaScript Code, i'm getting confused to make regular expression of such complex lines.

can we get the data in PHP in following format??

```
Array
(
    [lat] => 36.299484
    [lon] => -94.173695
    [id] =>  2498
    [name] => Rogers
    [phoneNumber] => (479) 986-1100
    [city] => Rogers
    [state] => AR
    [zipcode] => 72758
```

)

This is my incomplete approach..

```
   $fp = fopen("file.csv","w");
    $contents = file_get_contents('http://sites.target.com/site/en/spot/search_results.jsp?&mapType=enhanced&startAddress=72756&startingLat=36.322757720947266&startingLong=-93.99922943115234&_requestid=2573952');
    preg_match_all('Regular Expression Here', $contents, $matches);        
    foreach ($matches[1] as $index) {       
        preg_match('Regular Expression Here', $contents, $matches);
        preg_match_all('Regular Expression Here', $matches [1], $matches);
        $c = count ($matches [1]);
        $results = array();
        for ($i=0; $i<$c; $i++)  {
            $results [$matches [1] [$i]] = trim($matches [2] [$i], "\'");
        }
        fwrite($fp,implode(";",array_values($results))."\r\n");
    }
    fclose($fp);
```

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: i've updated my question, i've problem in making regex of such complicated lines

Comment: can u also suggest me any good study material to get expertise in regular expressions of such kind of complex codes. i've very basic understanding of regex and want to get expertise so that i can make any kind of regulr expression. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't bother with regular expressions if the format is fixed like in your example.

What I would do is:

1. Use `file` instead of `file_get_contents` to get the contents in an array (one line of the file per array element);
2. Loop through the array;
3. Use some of the many string functions to check for `results[results.length] =` and remove everything before that including `results[results.length] =` itself;
4. use `trim` to get rid of spaces at the end and the beginning and the trailing `;`
5. use `json_decode` to decode the remaining json object, see [this example](http://codepad.org/YT9myFS7).

Comment: Thanks Sir, It is really helpful for me.   actually format of the array will remain same but number of arrays will depend upon the input variable in this url "http://sites.target.com/site/en/spot/store_locator_new.jsp"  using post parameters.  i'll appreciate if you help me in regex..

Comment: @WQS But while you loop through the array (step 2.), you will get all arrays so you can store the processed results from step 5. in a new array. What do you need a regex for specifically?

Comment: ok sir i'm gonna follow your steps, actually i tried regex for some other website and it worked fine (code given at bottom of question), the line of codes inside the GetMap()  are available in html source of webpage.  so that's why i asked what regex should i use to scrap those arrays inside the GetMap() function.

Answer (score 1):

The information is in a format known as JSON.  PHP has a JSON parser.

http://php.net/manual/en/book.json.php

Comment: thanks, but my question was related to scraping that data from html source of that webpage, i need help to make regular expression to scrap that info from html.

Comment: So scrape everything between "var results = new Array();" to "};" and you've got a json object.  Run it through json_decode() as @OmnipotentEntity said, and you're home free.

Comment: nageeb, not really. You'd still have the JS code that creates the array to deal with. That's nothing a JSON parser will handle.